# How can I check if a xls file is editable file or not, using phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

I have this input file bootstrap:

[image]

This input file only accept xls file, when I send the xls file, first I need check in php if the file is only read or not and return a specific number, because I need accept only editable files.

Example what I need:

I send a xls file, in php I check if is a editable file , if is editable file , continue with the next step, and if is not a editable file, return 3.

This is a only read file:

[image]

I work with phpexcel and when I send a only read file , I have the next error:

[image]

This is my code in php:

```
<?php

require "dao/daoExcel.php";
require "vendor/autoload.php";

class ControllerExcel {

    private $aDatosExcel;

    public function setDataExcel($dataexcel) {

        $estado = true;

        if($this->moverArchivo($dataexcel)==false){
            $estado = false;
        }

        if($estado == true && $this->validaHeaders($dataexcel)==false){
            $estado = false;
            return 2;
        }

        if($estado == true){
            return $this->setInsertExcel($dataexcel);
        }

    }

    public function moverArchivo($dataexcel) {


        $fileName = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"]; 
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];
        $aHeader = new DaoExcel();
        $excelUrl = $aHeader->getHeaderExel($dataexcel);

        $pathAndName = $excelUrl[17]['par_valor'].$fileName;

        $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);
        if ($moveResult == true) {
           return true;
        }else{
           return false;
        }

    }

    public function validaHeaders($dataexcel){

        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $aHeader = new DaoExcel();
        $excelHead = $aHeader->getHeaderExel($dataexcel);
        $inputFileName = $excelHead[17]['par_valor'].$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

        $h1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getValue();
        $h2 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getValue();
        $h3 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C1')->getValue();
        $h4 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D1')->getValue();
        $h5 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E1')->getValue();

        $header = $h1."###".$h2."###".$h3."###".$h4."###".$h5;

        if($excelHead[16]['par_valor'] == $header){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }

    public function setInsertExcel($dataexcel){

        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $aHeader = new DaoExcel();
        $excelHead = $aHeader->getHeaderExel($dataexcel);
        $inputFileName = $excelHead[17]['par_valor'].$_FILES["archivo"]["name"];
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        $contRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();

        for($i=2;$i<=$contRows;$i++){
            $h1 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A'.$i)->getValue();
            $h2 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B'.$i)->getValue();
            $h3 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C'.$i)->getValue();
            $h4 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$i)->getValue();
            $h5 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('E'.$i)->getValue();
            $aDatos['ac_no']=$h1;
            $aDatos['custom_no']=$h2;
            $aDatos['nombre']=$h3;
            $aDatos['marc']=$h4;
            $aDatos['estado']=$h5;
            $aDatos['fecha_registro']=$this->setFecha();
            $aDatos['rco_oculto']=0;
            $this->aDatosExcel[]=$aDatos;
        }
        return $aHeader->insertDatosExcel($this->aDatosExcel);
    }

    private function setFecha(){

        date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
        $now = time();
        putenv("TZ=America/Santiago");
        $fecha=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$now);
        $date=date("Y/m/d H:i:s", strtotime($fecha));
        return $date;

    }

}

?>
```

So I see that by default,phpexcel only accept editable files , but how can I check by my self if a xls file is only read or not with phpexcel ,  and return a message?

Sorry by my english.

Comment: Your English is plenty good enough to understand your question.  No apology is necessary.

Comment: @wallyk ok , thank you

Comment: Just because a file has a `.xls` extension, doesn't mean that it's a BIFF-format Excel file.... because it's common to have csv, SpreadsheetML or even raw html markup files with an extension of .xls.... You should use the IOFactory's `identify()` method to determine whether it really is BIFF format (return should be `Excel5` for a real BIFF-format file)

Comment: If you open the file in MS EXcel, and then do "Save As", then the "Save as type" selector dropdown should also give you an indication of what format the file really is

Comment: @MarkBaker Hi , sorry but,I am new using phpexcel , can you tell me an advice with more details of how use correctly identify() , in relation with my code?, I need in my code: " If is a read only file , return 3 , if is not a read only file , continue with the next step "

Comment: Have a read of the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/wiki/User%20Documentation%20Reading%20Spreadsheet%20Files)

Comment: @MarkBaker I solved my problem using identify() thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $objPHPExcel->getSecurity()->isSecurityEnabled() ? 'some security is enabled' : 'no security is enabled';
```

[source](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/DocumentSecurity.php#L78)